# Pass AngularJS variables into Rails tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hi I have a table in a html.erb file

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in TableContent">
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
    <td>{{record.directory}}</td>
    <td>{{record.creation_date}}</td>
    <td>{{record.updated_date}}</td>
    <td><%= render :partial => '/table_content/entry_actions',
                   :local => {:entry => record } %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is possible for me to use the Angular `record` variable into the `:local` field of Rails `render` tag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to understand that the ruby code is executed on the server's side whereas the javascript is executed on the client's side. The ruby code is interpreted at a different level than the Javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, record should be a javascript variable and will raise an exception here as record is not defined, only if you have the data in the backend as a ruby variable you can pass to it as render will be evaluated in the backend,

if you want to achieve that, i suggest to have this partial as a template and render it from client side with Angular.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggestion. :)